# How to put Treeviews into MVC 3 views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, treeview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC 3 Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519934/asp-net-mvc-3-treeview)

I have managed to populate a treeview with my controller only I'm struggling as to how to actually get it onto my view!

Do I need to add an extention to the @Html. helpers? because I have been searching around the intellisense and cannot find treeview anywhere.

Please could someone explain what the deal is with MVC 3 and treeviews, and possible ways of putting them into views (simpler the better!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, look into this [ASP.NET MVC 3 Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519934/asp-net-mvc-3-treeview)
And next time try to use search first before posting. Thanks.

Comment: Helper which suggested in that post not really complicated. Moreover, it's ready. Just use it. Don't think you could find anything easier.