# Parent Folders and TreeView model design in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, treeview, subdirectory

Hey all Im new to MVC and have a few questions about creating treeviews and parent folders.

I did some searching and found this link but found it wasn't what I was after, so either a simpler explanation or alternative links would be great, and if I missed a search link please tell me the keywords you used in the search so I don't miss it next time.

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519934/asp-net-mvc-3-treeview)

Basically the website will load a table from the database and put them in the correct order, with a treeview like list on the left and a grid view of that level in the main area of the screen.

```
FolderID,FolderName,ParentID,ClientID
```

1. If a folder has a ParentID that equals another folder ID then it is the child of that   folder.
2. If a ParentID equals 0 then that Folder Is on the highest level.

Then we have a Groups and Groups permissions table, the Groups as you can imagine is simply

```
GroupID,GroupName,ClientId
```

and Group permissions is

```
GroupID,FolderID,HasRead
```

I need advise designing the models and treeview so that the page loads a list of folders based off if the group has permission to read them.

The left side of the page would load a treeview like list of all folders that group can see while the main area would load the level the user is on, if I clicked folder 1and folder 1 has a parentID of 5 all folders with parentID 5 will be displayed on the grid.

Can I get some advice on designing the models and loading the 2 lists properly for this? I've set this up in webforms but MVC feels so different I figured it was best to ask for help.

**Edit:** I'm currently having issues with the left area, I'm struggling to word the issue, How do I display a list of Folders a user has permission to see.

Since its a table of data between folders and Groups how do I create the models so that when I display the FolderPermissions table it shows data from both tables and can be filtered by say GroupID & HasRead = 1